# Python win32 service starting automatically

Tags: python, windows-services, pywin32

I am writing a python win32 service below are snippet of my code when i compile the service it works but i need to go to services.msc and start it manually.

Is there an option when i install the serivce by : myservice.exe install it will starts automaticly ?

below are snippet of my code :

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event

class SmallestPythonService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
   _svc_name_ = "ser_name"
   _svc_display_name_ = "ser_descryption"
   #_svc_description_='ddd'
   def __init__(self, args):

      win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
                    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):

       self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
       win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

   def SvcDoRun(self):

       win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

if __name__=='__main__':

    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(SmallestPythonService)
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `myservice.exe --startup=auto install` to install the service and set it to be started automatically.

Comment: Nativ solution is best solution!

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at this [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551780-win-services-helper/).  It's a wrapper around the win32serviceutil that shows how to auto-start the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sc.exe` with the `create` command.

```
sc create MyPyService binPath= "C:\myservice.exe" DisplayName= "Some Python Service"
```

More on this at [Microsoft KB251192](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

*win32serviceutil* also has a `InstallService()` function you might be able to use.

Comment: when i start the service using `sc start MyPyService`  i get the error. `[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

Answer (score -1):

@Maciejg doesn't work for me, here the solution to start automaticaly my service builded with py2exe :

```
myservice.exe -auto -install
```